# Salesforce restrict custom object to create lookup field for Task object

Tags: custom-object, lookup, tasks

I am currently developing an application in salesforce and my application requires that my custom object has a lookup field for Task object. Suddenly salesforce doesn't support this feature. What is the reason why salesforce restrict custom object to create lookup field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be below link would be useful to understand why Custom Object does not have lookup to Task Object.

[Can you create a Lookup to a Task?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79794/can-you-create-a-lookup-to-a-task)